# Change 360 images when click button with Panolen.js

Tags: javascript, html, button

I'm very new to html, css and javascript. So basically I have a page to display 360 panorama images, and I want the picture to change when I click on a button. For example I have button 1 to display image1, and button 2 to display image2.

What I've tried is to create a button on html file:

```
<button onclick="functionName(insertedName.value)">Image1</button>
```

and call the function on js file:

```
function functionName(){
    const panoramaImage = new PANOLENS.ImagePanorama("images/image3.jpg");
        const imageContainer = document.querySelector(".image-container");
        const viewer = new PANOLENS.Viewer({
        container: imageContainer,
});
viewer.add(panoramaImage);
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work, do I misunderstand anything because I'm very new. Any help and explanation would help a lot, thanks!

Comment: you call `functionName(insertedName.value)` ... but `function functionName(){` takes no arguments ... hard to see what your code is even trying to do

Comment: `"I have button 1 to display image1, and button 2 to display image2"` - does that continue for all 360 images or are you trying to find a way to perhaps have only two buttons  -one for next image and one for previous?

Comment: Where & how do you obtain the names/filepaths of the 360 panorama images? Do you run a SQL query? Scan a folder? Follow a known naming pattern with numeric suffixes etc?

Comment: I have a folder: index.html, style.css and main. js, there are two more subfolders: images: where I store 360 images (online downloaded), and js: which contains panolens.min.js and three.min.js. These are all from online tutorials.

The 360 image is displayed in a <div class="image-container">3d image display</div>

Comment: are the files named, for instance, `image3.jpg`, `image4.jpg `etc until `image360.jpg`? If you want to navigate through all 360 images you need to know the names/paths

Comment: The origial js is displayed the images/image3.jpg. What I want is when I click another button it will display images/image2.jpg instead

Comment: No it's a 360 image, a 360 panorama image

Comment: I appreciated that they are 360degree panorama images but the wording suggested 360 images... not to worry, how many images in total are you dealing with that you wish to load on clicks?

Comment: I have only 2 360panorama images. What I want is that when I click on button 1, it displays image1, and button 2 for image2. The thing is that the destination of the file is on the js file: const panoramaImage..."images/image3.jpg". How do I change this to "images/image2.jpg" for example, when I click on a button

Comment: it is hard to know whether simply  supplying a new image path to `viewer.add(..path..)` will accomplish what you want. If it does then that should be easy - having never used that particular js library I have no way of knowing

Answer (score 1):

Having never used Panlolens it took a bit of time to figure out a method of changing the loaded panorama image and even now I don't know if it is the best approach.

As you have only two images of known names my approach was to load the paths of both images into an array so that a simple 1 or 0 could be used to select an image via the assigned `dataset` attribute on the button itself. There are other ways to do this.

```js
const d = document;
d.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const viewer = new PANOLENS.Viewer({
    'container': d.querySelector('.image-container')
  });


  const images = [
    '//pchen66.github.io/Panolens/examples/asset/textures/equirectangular/field.jpg',
    '//static.wixstatic.com/media/28cb8a_02e9916ab748463bab3a0241d249231a~mv2.jpg'
  ];

  viewer.add(new PANOLENS.ImagePanorama(images[1]));


  d.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', e => {
    /* toggle a dataset attribute to select correct image from array */
    e.target.dataset.index = 1 - e.target.dataset.index;
    /* select the new image from array */
    let imgpath = images[Number(e.target.dataset.index)];
    
    /* dispose of previous image and load new */
    viewer.dispose();
    viewer.add(new PANOLENS.ImagePanorama(imgpath));
  })
})
```

```css
body,
body * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

button {
  width: 100px;
  position:absolute;
  top:1rem;
  left:1rem;
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
}

.image-container {
  height: 100vh;
}

.image-container:before {
  content: attr(data-image);
}
```

```html
<script src='//pchen66.github.io/js/three/three.min.js'></script>
<script src='//pchen66.github.io/js/panolens/panolens.min.js'></script>


<button data-index=1>Change image</button>
<div class='image-container'></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! With your code I've learnt quite a bit about querySelector and EventListener. My solution to this is to have buttons with their ids. Inside that I just put:

    viewer.dispose();
    viewer.add(new PANOLENS.ImagePanorama("images/image1.jpg"));

Same for other buttons.

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const viewer = new PANOLENS.Viewer({
    'container': document.querySelector('.image-container')
  });


  viewer.add(new PANOLENS.ImagePanorama("//pchen66.github.io/Panolens/examples/asset/textures/equirectangular/field.jpg"));

  document.querySelector('#button1').addEventListener('click', e => {
    viewer.dispose();
    viewer.add(new PANOLENS.ImagePanorama("//pchen66.github.io/Panolens/examples/asset/textures/equirectangular/field.jpg"));
  })

  document.querySelector('#button2').addEventListener('click', e => {
    viewer.dispose();
    viewer.add(new PANOLENS.ImagePanorama("//l13.alamy.com/360/2CWBB80/the-albert-memorial-in-kensington-gardens-london-picture-credit-mark-pain-alamy-stock-photo-2CWBB80.jpg"));
  })

  document.querySelector('#button3').addEventListener('click', e => {
    viewer.dispose();
    viewer.add(new PANOLENS.ImagePanorama("//l13.alamy.com/360/RB2CA4/bucheon-south-korea-december-13-2018-panorama-360-degrees-angle-view-of-snow-covered-park-on-a-sunny-day-RB2CA4.jpg"));
  })

})
```

```css
.image-container{
    height: 30rem;

    position: relative;
    width: 55%;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-left: 25%;
    overflow: hidden;
    
  border: 2px solid #ebb47a;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
   <script src='//pchen66.github.io/js/three/three.min.js'></script>
   <script src='//pchen66.github.io/js/panolens/panolens.min.js'></script>
   
   <button id="button1">Image1</button>
   <button id="button2">Image2</button>
   <button id="button3">Image3</button>

   <div class="image-container">3d image display</div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).